# how to get parameter names from an expression tree?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have a expression of this type:

```
Expression<Action<T>> expression
```

how do I get the parameters names from this expression (optional: and values) ?

example:

```
o => o.Method("value1", 2, new Object());
```

names could be str_par1, int_par2, obj_par3

Comment: by values I meant o => o.Method( "value") // Method(string s) s is name

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Expression<Action<Thing>> exp = o => o.Method(1, 2, 3);
var methodInfo = ((MethodCallExpression)exp.Body).Method;
var names = methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(pi => pi.Name);
```

Comment: For those looking to do the same for a constructor call, cast the body to `NewExpression` and access the `.Constructor` property. I did this for handling name changes when testing that the ctor throws `ArgumentNullExceptions` and includes the name of the arg in the message without hard coding the name in the test.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the parameter names from the `Parameters` property.

For example:

```
    Expression<Action<string, int>> expr = (a, b) => (a + b).ToString();
var names = expr.Parameters.Select(p => p.Name);  //Names contains "a" and "b"
```

For the second part, lambda expressions are just uncompiled functions.
Their parameters don't have values until you compile the expression and call the delegate with some values.

If you take the lambda expression `i => i.ToString()`, where are there any parameter values?

Comment: I actually wanted the names of the parameters of the method o => o.Method(par1, par2, par3)

Answer (score 3):

The parameters for `Method`? Get the `MethodInfo` from the expression (at a guess, [`MethodCallExpression.Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression.method.aspx)), and then use [`MethodBase.GetParameters()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) to get the parameters. ([`ParameterInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.aspx) has various useful properties, including [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.name.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get the parameters names from this expression ?

```
expression.Parameters[0].Name
```

For your future reference, the documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359453.aspx

> (optional: and values) ?

This doesn't make any sense to me. Can you explain what you mean by "and values"?

Comment: by values I meant o => o.Method( "value") // Method(string s) s is name

Comment: I actually wanted the names of the parameters of the method o => o.Method(par1, par2, par3)

Answer (score 2):

> I actually wanted the names of the parameters of the method o => o.Method(par1, par2, par3)

You have some belief that we're psychic, perhaps.

Anyway, moving on.

> I actually wanted the names of the parameters of the method o => o.Method(par1, par2, par3)

The name of the first formal parameter is:

```
(expression.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method.GetParameters()[0].Name
```

The expression which is the first argument is

```
(expression.Body as MethodCallExpression).Arguments[0]
```

For your future reference, the documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression.arguments.aspx